# Including a JPA-Project in a JAX-RS REST-Service Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence, jax-rs

I have written a JPA-Project which encapsulates all my entities. Since these entities are also needed in the REST-Service project I exported the JPA-Project as a *.jar and included it in the REST-project (this has no JPA-Facet).

So everything can be deployed on the server and I can reach the REST-services from the frontend, but as soon as the EntityManager should be injected in a class nothing happens.
This results in NullPointerExceptions since the entityManager is not present.

The classes in which to inject are marked as `@Stateless` and the entityManager with the `@PersistenceContext` annotation.

So the question is: does injection work in a nested project or do I have to instantiate the entityManager manually?

Thanks in advance!

In Addition, I am using Glassfish v 3.1.2 and JPA 2.0

Comment: If you use NetBeans 6.9+ there is a wizard that does exactly what you are looking for, with entity classes, Jersey annotations, Stateless DAOs, injection of the EntityManager. It's worth the effort of downloading this IDE. When you have understood the logic, you can continue with your preferred IDE

Comment: Right now i am using eclipse indigo but i will download Netbeans right away and try it.

Comment: This tutorial will help you: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html

Comment: Unfortunately Netbeans seems not to be able to create services based on my entities (0 files addded). If created from the database the entities are in the same project and not in a separated one which brings me back to my problem... The usage of the annotations is just like in my case though. Im confused...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going to answer my own question.
With the help of netbeans I gathered some information that made me change my project structure lightly.

This is what i've done:

- Giving the REST-Project the JPA-facet
- Store the persistence.xml in that project
- in the PU link to the jar which contains the entites

This way all i have to do is pass the injected entityManager into the entity-project and i am done!